# FInd if the fifth position is a letter and not a number using ORACLE

Tags: oracle

How can I find if the fifth position is a letter and thus not a number using Oracle ?

My last try was using the following statement:

```
REGEXP_LIKE (table_column, '([abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvxyz])');
```

Comment: After a while i found a solution : DECODE(
LPAD(
SUBSTR(
SUBSTR(collumn,regexp_instr(collumn, 'myfield:')+9,7)
,5),1), 
'A','is character A',
'B','is character B',
'C','is character C',
'D','is character D',
'E','is character E',
'F','is character F',
'G','is character G',
'H','is character H',
'I','is character I',
'J','is character J',
'is number')

Comment: Why only lowercase?

Comment: What about characters like =-+^%$# ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you'd rather check whether 5th position contains a number (which means that it is not *something else*), i.e. do the opposite of what you're doing now.

Why? Because a "letter" isn't only ASCII; have a look at the 4th row in my example - it contains Croatian characters and these aren't between [a-z] (nor [A-Z]).

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select 'abc_3def' from dual union all
  3     select 'A435D887' from dual union all
  4     select '!#$%&/()' from dual union all
  5     select 'ASDĐŠŽĆČ' from dual
  6    )
  7  select col,
  8    case when regexp_like(substr(col, 5, 1), '\d+') then 'number'
  9         else 'not a number'
 10    end result
 11  from test;

COL           RESULT
------------- ------------
abc_3def      number
A435D887      not a number
!#$%&/()      not a number
ASDĐŠŽĆČ      not a number

SQL>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
REGEXP_LIKE (table_column, '^....[a-z]')
```

Or:

```
SUBSTR (table_column, 5, 1 ) BETWEEN 'a' AND 'z'
```

Comment: Cool, but why would the answer not look for uppercase or at least translate to either upper- or lowercase?

Answer (score 1):

Anchor to the start of the string else you may get unexpected results.  This works, but remove the caret (start of string anchor) and it returns 'TRUE'!  Note it uses the case-insensitive flag of 'i'.

```
select 'TRUE'
from dual
where regexp_like('abcd4fg', '^.{4}[A-Z]', 'i');
```

Answer (score 1):

Yet another way to do it:

```
regexp_like(table_column, '^....[[:alpha:]]')
```

Using the character class [[:alpha:]] will pick up all letters upper case, lower case, accented and etc. but will ignore numbers, punctuation and white space characters.

If what you care about is that the character is not a number, then use

```
not regexp_like(table_column, '^....[[:digit:]]')
```

or

```
not regexp_like(table_column, '^....\d')
```